# How to configure port forwarding to docker container on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to deploy containerized application on google app engine. Deployment successful, but I cant access application on container port.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:10
ADD target/scala-2.12/server.jar /app/server.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app/server.jar
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

network:
  forwarded_ports:
    - 9999
```

On `https://xxx.appspot.com:9999` i get `502` code. Any suggestion?

**upd**

From [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080):

> The App Engine front end will route incoming requests to the
>   appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that your
>   application code is listening on 8080.

I will post some feedback later

Comment: You may not access the forwarded port by the appspot DNS and must use an instance IP. You must also open the port in the firewall. Both are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080):

> The App Engine front end will route incoming requests to the
>   appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that your
>   application code is listening on 8080.

So I switch server port to 8080 without any firewall manipulations and normaly access `https://xxx.appspot.com` at 80 port